# Error for some specific values in Matrix exponential

Tags: functions, matrix, linear-algebra, warning-messages

I have a matrix I would like to calculate the exponential of it.

```
tI = 0.000;
a  = 1;
dt = 0.001;

HSm[t_, k_] := {{0, -(0.9 Cos[t] + 
  1*(Cos[ k a] + I Sin[k a]))}, {-(0.9 Cos[t] + 
  1*(Cos[ k a] - I Sin[k a])), 0}};

MatrixExp[I (tI + 2 dt)*HSm[(tI + 2 dt), k]]
DistributeDefinitions[HSm, tI1, dt1];

far[k_] = 
   ParallelTable[
    MatrixExp[I (tI1 + j dt1)*HSm[(tI1 + j dt1), k]], {j, 20, 
     0, -1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
far[k_] /. {k -> 0.01}
```

I am getting error for this evaluation as:

```
MatrixExp::eivn: Incorrect number 0 of eigenvectors for eigenvalue -1. Sqrt[-7.23999*10^-6-7.19999*10^-6 Cos[k]] with multiplicity 1.
```

What is the reason for this? because when I use `t = tI + n dt`, where `n = 2, 5, 12, 14, 19, 22, 23, ..., 745, ..`. I get this error but not for in between numbers i.e. `n = 0, 1, 3, 4, ...`. `k` is a variable, which take value from `[-\[Pi],\[Pi]]`
Can I avoid this error or resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using using inexact numbers like 0.0, 0.001, 0.9, we can use exact values like 0, 1/1000 and 9/10.  Also, the factor `1*` two places looks suspicious.  One way to avoid the error message is

```
ClearAll[HSm, t, k, a, tI, n, dt]
HSm[t_, k_] := {{0, -(9/10 Cos[t] + (Cos[k a] + I Sin[k a]))}, {-(9/
         10 Cos[t] + (Cos[k a] - I Sin[k a])), 0}};

f = MatrixExp[I (tI + n dt)*HSm[(tI + n dt), k]];
```

Then we can replace `tI`, `n`, `dt`, etc as we wish.  Or, if we want to define `tI=0` and `dt=1/1000` before doing the matrix exponentiation, we can.

The idea is that we evaluate `MatrixExp[]` first with exact values and then introduce inexact values afterwards.  Here is one approach

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
HSm[t_, k_] := {{0, -(0.9 Cos[t] + (Cos[k a] + 
        I Sin[k a]))}, {-(0.9 Cos[t] + (Cos[k a] - I Sin[k a])), 0}}

f = MatrixExp[I (tI + j dt)*HSm[(tI + j dt), k]];

a = 1.0; tI = 0.0; dF = 0.03; dt = 0.01;

g = f /. k -> 0.01;
DistributeDefinitions[g];
far = ParallelTable[g // Chop, {j, 2000, 0, -1}];

ColumnForm[MatrixForm /@
  RandomChoice[far, 3]]
```

In the above, we prefer to evaluate the `f = ...` first, before the `a = ...`, to avoid the error message.  The calculation of `g` is an intermediate step that let us see what expression we are sending to `ParallelTable[]`.  The final command will display only a few of the matrices that are calculated.

Comment: I changed it like this but it didn't solve anything. This is [what i got](http://imgur.com/8yp55mB)

Comment: @L.K. You need to change `tI` to exact 0 too.

Comment: Thanks @LouisB It did work but it seems that there are still some values(creating problems). This is [my complete program](http://imgur.com/wcwLsWz)

Comment: @L.K. I added `ClearAll[ ... ]` before the function definition.  Thanks to @W.Mason.

Comment: It worked many thanks. But I will be using numerical values for `k` will it be problem as we have change everything to exact number. `k` will be from $-\pi$ to $\pi$. In some discrete $ d k = 0.01$.

Comment: This is [what I am getting for `k`](http://imgur.com/a/aP3VQ)

Comment: It looks like you want `far[k_]:=` instead of `far[k_]=`.  You may want to edit your question to add the complete program.  Also, for test purposes, we can use something smaller than 2000.

Comment: @LouisB Thank you for points. I couldn't see your comment(it was missing my name). Anyway I have edited my question

Comment: @L.K.  I added a section of code that shows the steps I might use to calculate the list of matrices.

Answer (score 2):

### **This is only a comment**

This is what you get if you replace ALL the inexact numbers [image]

Comment: It worked many thanks. But I will be using numerical values for $k$ will it be problem as we have change everything to exact number. $k$ will be from $−π$ to $π$. In some discrete $dk=0.01$.