# Incorrect number # of eigenvectors for eigenvalue

Tags: functions, matrix, linear-algebra, warning-messages

I have the following code:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
(*Input parameters*)
fp = 6.0; (*Pump Frequency*)
ϕ0 = 207/100;
LL = 1/10;
a = 10;(*μm*)
r = 1/2;
Cj = 329/10^6;(*nF*)
CC = 39/10^6;(*nF*)

(*Definitions*)
ωp = 2.0*π*fp;
detu[Δ_] := 2*π*Δ;
ωs[Δ_] := ωp - detu[Δ];
ωi[Δ_] := ωp + detu[Δ];
ωth = 3.0*ωp;
zchar = Sqrt[LL/CC];
I0 = ϕ0/(2.0*π*LL);
Ip = r*I0;
ω0 = 1.0/Sqrt[LL*CC];
RR = 10^4/(CC*ω0);
ωpt = ωp/ω0;
ωst[Δ_] := ωs[Δ]/ω0;
ωit[Δ_] := ωi[Δ]/ω0;
ωtht = ωth/ω0;
β = Cj/CC;
δ0 = 1.0/(RR*CC*ω0);
kpt = ωpt/Sqrt[1.0 - β*ωpt^2];
kst[Δ_] := ωst[Δ]/Sqrt[1.0 - β*(ωst[Δ])^2];
kit[Δ_] := ωit[Δ]/Sqrt[1.0 - β*(ωit[Δ])^2];
ktht = ωtht/Sqrt[1.0 - β*ωtht^2];
Ap0t = (Ip*zchar)/(ωp*LL*I0);
αpt = kpt^5/(16.0*ωpt^2)*Ap0t^2;
αtht = (kpt^2*ktht^3)/(8.0*ωtht^2)*Ap0t^2;

Γst[Δ_] := (kst[Δ]*δ0)/ωst[Δ];
Γit[Δ_] := (kit[Δ]*δ0)/ωit[Δ];

C2 = (kpt^3*(2.0*kpt - ktht)*ktht)/(16.0*ωpt^2);
D2 = -((kpt^4*ktht)/(16.0*ωtht^2));
U1[Δ_] := (kpt^2*kst[Δ]^3)/(8.0 ωst[Δ]^2);
U2[Δ_] := ((2.0*kpt - kit[Δ])*kpt^2*kst[Δ]*kit[Δ])/(16.0*(ωst[Δ])^2);
U3[Δ_] := ((kpt + kit[Δ] - ktht)*kpt*ktht*kst[Δ]*kit[Δ])/(8.0*(ωst[Δ])^2);

V1[Δ_] := (kpt^2*kit[Δ]^3)/(8.0 ωit[Δ]^2);
V2[Δ_] := ((2.0*kpt - kst[Δ])*kpt^2*kst[Δ]*kit[Δ])/(16.0*(ωit[Δ])^2);
V3[Δ_] := ((kpt + kst[Δ] - ktht)*kpt*ktht*kst[Δ]*kit[Δ])/(8.0*(ωit[Δ])^2);

ΔkL[Δ_] := 2.0*kpt - kst[Δ] - kit[Δ];
Δkth = 3.0*kpt - ktht + 3.0*αpt - αtht;

Ap[x_] := Ap0t*E^(I*αpt*x) + I*(C2*D2*Ap0t^5*E^(I*αpt*x))/Δkth*(x + (E^(-I*Δkth*x) - 1.0)/(I*Δkth));
Ath[x_] := D2/Δkth*Ap0t^3*E^(I*αtht*x)*(E^(I*Δkth*x) - 1.0)

(*Matrix Exponential*)
MM[xp_, Δ_] := Simplify[{{I*U1[Δ]*ComplexExpand[Abs[Ap[xp]]^2] - Γst[Δ]/2, I*U2[Δ]*E^(I*ΔkL[Δ]*xp)*ComplexExpand[(Ap[xp])^2] + I*U3[Δ]*Conjugate[Ap[xp]]*Ath[xp]*E^(I*(ktht - kpt - kst[Δ] - kit[Δ])*xp)}, {-I*V2[Δ]*E^(-I*ΔkL[Δ]*xp)*ComplexExpand[(Ap[xp])^2] - I*V3[Δ]*Ap[xp]*Conjugate[Ath[xp]]*E^(-I*(ktht - kpt - kst[Δ] - kit[Δ])*xp), -I*V1[Δ]*ComplexExpand[Abs[Ap[xp]]^2] - Γit[Δ]/2}}, Assumptions -> {xp >= 0, xp ∈ Reals}];
PP[xx_, Δ_] := Integrate[MM[y, Δ], {y, 0, xx}];
Smat[xx_, Δ_] := MatrixExp[PP[xx, Δ]];
```

Upon calling `Smat[x,0]`, I get the following error:

[image]

Based on my preliminary search of the problem ([here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143577/error-for-some-specific-values-in-matrix-exponential), and [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/102916)), it seems that the issue usually stems from not rationalizing the input parameters. But my input parameters were all rationalized. What is going on here?

**Edit:** Here is a screenshot of me printing the matrix `PP[x,0]`, which Mathematica has no problem printing for me.
[image]

Comment: (1) It takes some time to produce the 2x2 matrix you are trying to exponentiate. It has a leaf count around 48K. I've rune `Eigensystem` on it for several minutes with no result thus far (and it is possible that `MatrixExp` is coughing on a different-but-related matrix). I'm using a development kernel for this computation so perhaps something got worse in 13.3 (the lack of speed) or perhaps better (no error messages thus far). If you have details about input size and time needed please add them to the post.

Comment: (2) I do not know if this will make a difference to the outcome, but it does seem that several definitions in the code are in terms of inexact numbers.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau is it possible to give any unofficial very rough estimate on a time frame when 13.3 might be released?

Comment: @Nasser Not something I could say. Many moving parts...

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thank you for your response. I actually have no problem printing the matrix that I'm trying to exponentiate. In fact, if I run just `PP[x,0]`, it immediately returns the matrix with no problem (as a function of `x`). I have included the screenshot of it in my original post.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau For some more background. I am running version 12.0.0.0. Could you elaborate more on what you mean by inexact numbers? As far as I can tell, I have tried to rationalize all my input parameters. If you mean removing the decimals behind some prefactors (e.g. `16.0` to `16`), then I have tried that and the problem persists.

Comment: Thanks for the further details. It turns out I was working with `PP[xx, delta]` and not `PP[xx, 0]`. Changing that brings the leaf count to 525. And I can replicate the problem. So I'll look into it. But it might turn out to be unfriendly. I am guessing we get a zero test wrong due to the mix of symbolic things and machine numbers. If that turns out to be the case it might not be something I could improve.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thank you for your help. I am monitoring the post so feel free to ask about any details of the code that requires further clarification

Comment: Could you please add the message name for the error message?

Comment: "But my input parameters were all rationalized." -- Really?  I get `MachinePrecision` for the `Precision` of `MM[y, 0]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you for your response. What do you mean by message name for the error message? If you are asking about the details, it is the screenshot shown in the original message.

Comment: @MichaelE2 When I say my input parameters were all rationalized, I meant the numbers which enters my formula at the beginning (see `Input parameters` in the code above, second line). Given that the formulas are interconnected, I do not know how it percolates when it arrives to the matrix `MM`. Do you have any suggestions on what I should do?

Comment: For the message name, click on the three-dot button next to the error. Then click on copy message name. The message name can be used to search the site for related errors. (That might help you in this case, or help someone else in the future.) -- By "rationalized" in Mma, we usually mean exact instead of floating-point input. Use `8` instead of `8.0` for instance.  See also `Rationalize`. Sometimes it is bad to have floating-point (because of round-off error, typically, in, say, `Integrate`); sometimes it is bad to have exact (because of large, unwieldy expressions, when it's bad).

Answer (score 1):

As I had thought, the issue is that `Eigensystem` (and, by extension, `MatrixExp`) cannot deduce there is a null vector corresponding to each eigenvalue. This in turn is because the presence of symbolic input forces the eigensystem computation to compute a null space by row reduction, and it is effectively impossible to determine that a large nonpolynomial symbolic expression containing approximate numbers is zero.

There are two reasonable ways I know of to proceed. I think the better one is to simply compute the exponential for different values of the variable `xx` and perhaps interpolate from that. The "direct" way, which I do not think is numerically stable and might suffer various other ills, is to provide `Eigensystem` with a non-default zero test.

Here is the matrix in question.

```
pmat = {{(-0.00005121161524020216 + 0.0026178649909336586*I)*xx + 
   (0. + 3.993655784881471*^-12*I)*xx^3 + 
   (0. + 4.000111699067347*^-9*I)*xx*
    Cos[0.07739713430827709*xx] + (0. + 0.0000590771943669321*I)*
    Sin[0.07739713430827709*xx], 
  (1.5788343611162837*^-6*E^((0. + 0.0773971343082771*I)*xx) - 
    0.47712990394682414*E^((0. + 0.15217182721996186*I)*xx) - 
    0.05012997734894152*E^((0. + 0.1547942686165542*I)*xx) - 
    0.00001530065012797118*E^((0. + 0.22694652013164662*I)*xx) + 
    0.0017007732791776591*E^((0. + 0.2321914029248313*I)*xx) - 
    3.285851077155409*^-9*E^((0. + 0.30434365443992367*I)*xx) + 
    3.1763715703476475*^-9*E^((0. + 0.3095885372331083*I)*xx) - 
    (0. + 3.4842579271608996*^-6*I)*
     E^((0. + 0.1547942686165542*I)*xx)*xx + 
    (0. + 1.1418783646506823*^-7*I)*
     E^((0. + 0.2321914029248313*I)*xx)*xx + 
    (6.462222647503057*^-9*E^((0. + 0.306966095836516*I)*xx) + 
      E^((0. + 0.07477469291168475*I)*xx)*
       (-1.1557957707646625*^-24 - 
        (0. + 8.642427382755163*^-26*I)*xx) + 
      E^((0. + 0.22956896152823897*I)*xx)*
       (0.000029622594647121442 - 
        (0. + 1.9345090229089154*^-9*I)*xx) + 
      E^((0. + 0.15217182721996186*I)*xx)*(0.5255432008849645 - 
        (0. + 0.00006927475025946675*I)*xx - 
        2.2843155561479443*^-9*xx^2))*
     Cos[0.0026224413965923324*xx] + 
    ((0. - 1.0947950680776157*^-10*I)*
       E^((0. + 0.306966095836516*I)*xx) + 
      E^((0. + 0.07477469291168475*I)*xx)*
       ((0. - 1.1557957707646625*^-24*I) + 
        8.642427382755163*^-26*xx) + 
      E^((0. + 0.22956896152823897*I)*xx)*
       ((0. - 9.787056088209194*^-7*I) + 1.9345090229089154*^-9*
         xx) + E^((0. + 0.15217182721996186*I)*xx)*
       ((0. + 0.5255432008849645*I) + 0.00006927475025946675*
         xx - (0. + 2.2843155561479443*^-9*I)*xx^2))*
     Sin[0.0026224413965923324*xx])/
   E^((0. + 0.15217182721996186*I)*xx)}, 
 {0.5740137499557736 - 0.05012997734894152/
    E^((0. + 0.0026224413965923454*I)*xx) - 
   0.5255432008849648*E^((0. + 0.0026224413965923454*I)*xx) - 
   0.000015300650127971185/E^((0. + 0.07477469291168473*I)*xx) + 
   1.5788343611162841*^-6*E^((0. + 0.07477469291168476*I)*xx) + 
   0.0016864755101056526/E^((0. + 0.0800195757048694*I)*xx) - 
   0.000014297769072006634*E^((0. + 0.08001957570486945*I)*xx) - 
   3.285851077155408*^-9/E^((0. + 0.15217182721996186*I)*xx) - 
   3.1763715703476467*^-9*E^((0. + 0.1574167100131465*I)*xx) + 
   ((0. + 3.4842579271609005*^-6*I)*xx)/
    E^((0. + 0.0026224413965923454*I)*xx) + 
   (0. + 0.00006927475025946678*I)*
    E^((0. + 0.0026224413965923454*I)*xx)*xx - 
   ((0. + 1.1418783646506826*^-7*I)*xx)/
    E^((0. + 0.0800195757048694*I)*xx) + 
   2.284315556147945*^-9*E^((0. + 0.0026224413965923454*I)*xx)*
    xx^2 + E^((0. + 0.0026224413965923454*I)*xx)*
    (9.78705608820919*^-7 + (0. + 1.9345090229089154*^-9*I)*xx)*
    Cos[0.07739713430827709*xx] + 
   (1.1319599590726744*^-26/E^((0. + 0.0026224413965923454*I)*
        xx) + 1.094795068077615*^-10*
      E^((0. + 0.0026224413965923454*I)*xx))*
    Cos[0.15479426861655418*xx] - 
   (0. + 0.000029622594647121452*I)*
    E^((0. + 0.0026224413965923454*I)*xx)*
    Sin[0.07739713430827709*xx] - 1.9345090229089154*^-9*
    E^((0. + 0.0026224413965923454*I)*xx)*xx*
    Sin[0.07739713430827709*xx] + 
   (0. + 6.679677322243623*^-25*I)*Sin[0.15479426861655418*xx] + 
   ((0. + 6.681595028036278*^-25*I)*Sin[0.15479426861655418*xx])/
    E^((0. + 0.0026224413965923454*I)*xx) - 
   (0. + 6.462222647503055*^-9*I)*
    E^((0. + 0.0026224413965923454*I)*xx)*
    Sin[0.15479426861655418*xx], 
  (-0.00005121161524020216 - 0.0026178649909336586*I)*xx - 
   (0. + 3.993655784881471*^-12*I)*xx^3 - 
   (0. + 4.000111699067347*^-9*I)*xx*
    Cos[0.07739713430827709*xx] - (0. + 0.0000590771943669321*I)*
    Sin[0.07739713430827709*xx]}};
```

The zero assessment I'll use just plugs in a random real value for `xx` and checks if the result is beneath some threshold.

```
esys = Eigensystem[pmat,
    ZeroTest->(Abs[#/.xx->RandomReal[]]<10^(-4)&)];
```

This takes around a half second on my desktop machine and gives a full result for the eigenvectors.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is to get the matrix exponential of a  2x2 matrix with a free parameter t

```
      MatrixPower[ E,  t {{a,b},{c,d}}
```

A trivial problem: Diagonalize, calculate the power of the eigenvalues as a diagonal matrix, transform back using the eigensystem.

As a result, clear from the beginning: All matrix elements have the form

```
          a_ik Exp[t a_1 ] + b_ik Exp[t a_2]
```

Thats the kernel of any solution of time evolutions resulting from linear ODES.

You ran into the fact, that Wolfram Language's

> Integrate, NIntegrate

with definite integrals is a definite `no go`.

Whenever you have a non-trivial definite `Integrate`, the system begins a never ending search on the hard disk you can follow in the Task Manager.

In contradistinction, indefinite `Integrate` is functional as long as standard solving strategies are working.  But by any measure, the probability to write an indefinite integral yielding a closed finite algebraic expression as a result, is zero,  unfortunately.

Except if the probability measure is defined on the set of integrals from exercises.

So as in this case.

Define your integrals as functions of the upper limit

```
PP[xx_, \[CapitalDelta]_, y_] := Integrate[MM[xx, \[CapitalDelta]], y]

Smat[xx_, \[CapitalDelta]_, y] := MatrixExp[PP[xx, \[CapitalDelta], y]];
```

Comment: In no way does this address the question that was posed.

Comment: @Roland F Thank you for your response. I think I understand what you are trying to say but I'd like to clarify a few things. (1) The free parameter in my `MM` matrix would be `xp`, but the analogy to your `t` is not straightforward as it its not simply just a prefactor, it enters into an exponent in the matrix elements as well. (2) It is true that diagonalizing it might be easier, but it is unclear how to revert back to the eigen basis post integration, since `PP` is defined as the integral of `MM` (3) There is no concepts of probability here

Comment: @Roland F Can you elaborate on what you might do to resolve the error/warnings in my case?

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the problems by inactivating Exp, because I know that Mathemtica does not Simplify

```
   MM[xp_, \[CapitalDelta]_] :=
     Activate[With[{Exp = Inactive[Exp]},
    Evaluate[
     (Chop[# , 10^-16] &)@
       FullSimplify[{{I*U1[\[CapitalDelta]]*
      ComplexExpand[Abs[Ap[xp]]^2] - 
      \[CapitalGamma]st[\[CapitalDelta]]/2, 
     I*U2[\[CapitalDelta]]*
       Exp[(I*\[CapitalDelta]kL[\[CapitalDelta]]*xp)]*
       ComplexExpand[(Ap[xp])^2] + 
      I*U3[\[CapitalDelta]]*Conjugate[Ap[xp]]*Ath[xp]*
       Exp[(I*(ktht - kpt - kst[\[CapitalDelta]] - 
            kit[\[CapitalDelta]])*xp)]}, {-I*V2[\[CapitalDelta]]*
       Exp[(-I*\[CapitalDelta]kL[\[CapitalDelta]]*xp)]*
       ComplexExpand[(Ap[xp])^2] - 
      I*V3[\[CapitalDelta]]*Ap[xp]*Conjugate[Ath[xp]]*
       Exp[(-I*(ktht - kpt - kst[\[CapitalDelta]] - 
            kit[\[CapitalDelta]])*xp)], -I*V1[\[CapitalDelta]]*
       ComplexExpand[
        Abs[Ap[xp]]^2] - \[CapitalGamma]it[\[CapitalDelta]]/2}}, 
   Assumptions -> {NumericQ[xp] == True, xp >= 0, 
     xp \[Element] Reals}]]]];
```

Now there are complaints about my Assumptions, but in no time

```
         Smat[RandomReal[], RandomReal[]]

    {0.999991 + 0.000373264 I,   3.06243*10^-8 + 0.000258902 I},
 {-1.30875*10^-8 - 0.000191847 I,   0.999991 - 0.000536456 I}}
```

Its of course not sound, mathematically, insisting on xp to be numeric and the other conditons: it is a Pattern object. It is better style, to Simplify expressions first and then splice them into a function definition.

My standard in such cases is

```
  SetDelayed@@{ x_,  FullSimplify[expression]  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Just a few things: (1) If I simply run the `MM` as defined in your post with `Inactive[Exp]`, I get a warning saying `FullSimplify: Warning: one or more assumptions evaluated to False`. This is a warning that I get even when I ask to simply print `PP[x,0]`, which is something that I didn't get in my definition of `MM`. (2) I cannot use `RandomReal[]` for the arguments of Smat, because well, they are not random numbers. I don't quite get the overall purpose of your approach. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Design and conquer. First, write the mathematical expressions as functions with all constants as variables. Second, make all Simplify and complex expanding, TrigToExp and FullSimplify and define th result as a new function. Evaluate the functions with the constants and further FullSimplify. Check for occurencies of 0. and 1.*I etc and Rationalize eg by Rationalize[ expr,  2^-64] depending on the overall mean numeric entities.  Finally never do  a search for definite integrals. Indefinite integral evaluated at both boundaries are sound, and fast. If they dont deliver, resort to NIntegrate.